# I'm implementing a Binary Search tree in ruby but I'm having an issue with getting a node's parent

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

Due to the way the tree is initialized, any node is aware of it's children but not it's parent.

How can I find the parent without passing it in, or is that the only way?
Unless there's a way to automatically pass a reference to the parent in?

At the moment I create a tree like so:

```
Node[
    5,
    Node[
        2,
        nil,
        Node[
            3
        ]
    ],
    Node[
        9,
        node[
            7
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: What's the `Node[...` syntax? I would think this would really look like, `[5, [2, nil, [3, nil, nil]], [9, [7, nil, nil], nil]]`. Or possibly condensed to: `[5, [2, nil, [3]], [9, [7]]]` And I think you'll have to pass in the reference to the parent.

Comment: Why not simply pass the parent to your constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. You can set the parent when assigning `left` or `right`:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :key, :parent
  attr_reader :left, :right

  def self.[](key, left = nil, right = nil)
    new(key, left, right)
  end

  def initialize(key, left, right)
    @key = key
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
  end

  def left=(node)
    node.parent = self if node
    @left = node
  end

  def right=(node)
    node.parent = self if node
    @right = node
  end
end
```

Example:

```
root = Node[
         5,
         Node[
             2,
             nil,
             Node[
                 3
             ]
         ],
         Node[
             9,
             Node[
                 7
             ]
         ]
       ]

root.key #=> 5
root.left.key # => 2
root.left.parent.key #=> 5
root.left.parent == root #=> true
```

Comment: Thank, honestly speaking it just occured to me to do exactly this literally just a minute ago. I'm still going to tick this however as it's the correct answer.